# Example of linear transformations such that $T^2=0$ and $T^2(v)=-v$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

How to get a linear transformations $T: R^2 \rightarrow R^2$ such that

1. $T^2=0$
2. $T^2(v)=-v$

Please do not be specific with the answer. Is there a general method to solve both of them

Comment: Is this two questions, or do you want the same $T$ for (1) and (2)? Do you know any examples of either, that you might be able to generalize?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

1. If $T = O$, then $T^2 = \ldots$ (trivial, but easy)
2. Mapping $v$ to $-v$ is a rotation over $180^\circ$, so if $T^2$ should do that, then $T$...

Comment: i have a hunch OP was looking for a non-trivial map for (1). you can hint same as (2)...

Comment: $T^2=0$ does not necessarily imply $T=0$ so I think your hint for (1) is misleading.

Comment: @Bye_World True for the first part; I don't agree about being misleading. You want $T^2 = 0$, well simply take...

Comment: @Bye_World yes but OP did not specify he wanted a non-trivial map, just a linear one... but i have ahunch a non-trivial one would be better...

Comment: Ah.  I see.  I was interpretting it as "find all such $T$" or "characterize any such $T$".  OK then the zero map would definitely work *as written*.

Comment: @gt6989b Yes, possibly. But if that's not specified, it's also good to realize there's an easy example: why make it difficult? But agreed that it's useful nonetheless to try and come up with a non-trivial one.

Comment: @StackTD agreed

Answer (score 3):

There is no "general method" that can be applied here until you're very comfortable with how to use eigenvalues.  However, I'm pretty sure that they're only asking you this question because they are *going* to teach you about eigenvalues soon.

Here's a hint for the first one (assuming $T$ is supposed to be non-zero): define $T$ to be a projection onto the $x$-axis followed by a $90^\circ$ rotation.  Why does $T^2 = 0$?

For the second: $T^2(v) = -v$ rotates a vector by $180^\circ$ about the origin.  What transformation, when applied twice, rotates a vector by $180^\circ$?

Answer (score 2):

For (1), play around with matrix multiplications. What can you expect $T$ to be so that $T^2=0$?

> For instance, $T=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$.

For (2), the determinant of $T$ must be $1$ (can you see why?), which means $T$ is of the form 
$${\displaystyle T={\begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta &-\sin \theta \\\sin \theta &\cos \theta \\\end{bmatrix}}}.$$
It represents the [rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) on the plane. Note also that combinations of rotations are also rotations. Can you play around with some $\theta$ to see what can give you $T^2=-I$? A hint is that $-I$ corresponds to the rotation matrix with $\theta=\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix of $T$ has only four terms:
$$T=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$$

Compute $T^2$. Find the matrices of the applications $S_1(v)=0$ and $S_2(v)=-v$.

Equal $T$ to $S_1$ and $S_2$ and solve for $a,b,c,d$.

Note: I have used the same letter for the applications and thier matrices. I hope this not lead to confussion.